# Calling several functions with different default parameters from a function modifying the default values

Tags: python, function, parameters, keyword-argument, nested-function

I have several functions with default parameters, which are called from a high-level function and I would like to be able to modify a certain number of those parameters from the other functions. Let's put an example

```
def printing(what, n = 3):
    for _ in range(n):
        print(what)

def printing_number(number, i=3):
    for _ in range(i):
        print(number)

def outer(what, number):
    printing(what)
    printing_number(number)
```

`outer` is the function that is going to be called and I would like to being able to put something like
`outer('hello', 4, i = 4)` and then it will execute `printing('hello', n=3)` and `printing_number(4, i=4)`.

I have tried with **kwargs as follows:

```
def printing(what, n = 3):
    for _ in range(n):
        print(what)

def printing_number(number, i=3):
    for _ in range(i):
        print(number)
def outer(what, number, **kwargs):
    printing(what, **kwargs)
    printing_number(number, **kwargs)
```

However, it just works correctly with the default parameter, if I code `outer('hello',3,i=4)`, I will get an error saying that printing received an unexpected parameter.

So, is there a way that `i` is passed only to the function that has it as parameter?

Comment: Are you sure this is the easiest way to achieve what you're trying to do? It would probably make more sense in the long run to just have `outer` take `i` and `n` as normal parameters and pass them. Otherwise, if you wanted the caller to make use of the default arguments, they would need to memorize what `outer` calls internally, and what the default parameters for those functions are. That's probably more mental strain than necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem seems to be the fact that you are calling `printing(what, **kwargs)` but do not have the `**kwargs` keyword in the function definition. Just add `**kwargs` to your first function and things work fine

```
def printing(what, n = 3, **kwargs):
    for _ in range(n):
        print(what)


outer('hello', 4, i = 4)   
# hello
# hello
# hello
# 4
# 4
# 4
# 4
```